# ROS package template for Python package generation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any project templates for ROS Python packages which can be used with a project generator like [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287793/ros-package-template-for-python-package-generation/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-04-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
I don't know of anything distributed "officially" (ie: through some package or other distributable artefact from OSRF or the ROS buildfarm). I know of some work within ROSIN that goes in this direction (slightly further, code generation as well). Not sure when that will be released though.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-08**:
Would have been nice if one could streamline package skeleton generation a bit. In case you can provide info about...: What will the ROSIN generation deal with exactly (what will it generate)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
Package structure, nodes, topics, launch files, etc. A bit more than just a skeleton package. And based on a declarative data structure (essentially an xml file, nothing too fancy). And some expectation management: it's not a research topic in ROSIN, so this is a convenience tool.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-08**:
Sound helpful. Will this support ROS node packages (which include node/nodelet specific code) separate from ROS lib packages (which include code without any ROS dependencies despite of building)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
Note that the fact that I don't know about something for tools like `cookiecutter` doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look like this one is what you are looking for?

(https://github.com/simlei/cookiecutter-ros-python)

---

Originally posted by [DangTran](https://answers.ros.org/users/53085/dangtran/) with karma: 66 on 2020-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1